# Return multiple data from Case statement condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below SQl. Right now I only get the return as `<td class="HeaderData"> Year 1 </td>` since all conditions are satisfied in the below sql how can I get all the  ..Here is  the fiddle [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca0ba/2861)

```
Declare @ContractTerm int
Set @ContractTerm = 5

Select Case When @ContractTerm  >= 1 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 1 </td>'
   When @ContractTerm >=  2 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 2 </td>' 
   When @ContractTerm >= 3 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 3 </td>'
   When @ContractTerm  >= 4 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 4 </td>' 
   When @ContractTerm  >= 5 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 5 </td>' End
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting for output? CASE is an expression which is used to return a single value. As such the first condition is true so you get Year 1.

Comment: Your result will always have Year 1. Why don't you just use = 1 or = 2 instead of >=1 or >=2 etc.

Comment: Because if @ContractTerm  is 5 then I want all the conditions to return data..Sorry I am new to SQL

Comment: Did you mean if @ContractTerm = 5, then it should return for all conditions? Then it will return all of these?

<td class="HeaderData"> Year 1 </td>
<td class="HeaderData"> Year 2 </td>
<td class="HeaderData"> Year 3 </td>
<td class="HeaderData"> Year 4 </td>
<td class="HeaderData"> Year 5 </td>

Comment: This is corerct..If it is 3 then it will return  <td class="HeaderData"> Year 1 </td> <td class="HeaderData"> Year 2 </td> <td class="HeaderData"> Year 3 </td>

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you  doing this in the presentation layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will result to how many is declared on the @ContractTerm

```
DECLARE @ContractTerm INT
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @ContractTerm = 5
SET @Counter = 1

WHILE @Counter <= @ContractTerm
BEGIN
   SELECT '<td class="HeaderData"> Year ' + CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR) + ' </td>'

   SET @Counter += 1
END
```

Comment: Gosh a loop here is not needed. Looping should be avoided whenever possible and this is definitely possible without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to concatenate the conditions together?

```
Select ( (Case When @ContractTerm >= 1 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 1 </td>' else '' end) +
         (case When @ContractTerm >= 2 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 2 </td>' else '' end) +
         (case When @ContractTerm >= 3 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 3 </td>' else '' end) +
         (case When @ContractTerm >= 4 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 4 </td>' else '' end) +
         (case When @ContractTerm >= 5 Then '<td class="HeaderData"> Year 5 </td>' else '' end)
        ) as all_conditions
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not working..if the variable is 3 or something else it just returns null

Comment: @user1221989 are you sure??? It works perfectly using your sample data.